# awk Compare 2 files, print match and difference

Tags: text, awk, compare

I need to comapre two files f1.txt and f2.txt and obtain matches, and non-matches, for this case I am looking to match first field on both files. And print first the second field of f2.txt, then print the entire line of f1.txt. And for no match found on f2.txt to state "Not Found" and then print f1.txt entire line.

F1.txt

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
1a;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
1b;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
2b;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
```

F2.txt

```
1;First
1a;Firsta
1b;Firstb
```

Desired output:

```
First;1;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
Firsta;1a;1a;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
Firstb;1b;1b;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
Not Found;2b;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
```

I am able to obtain the matches but not the non match

```
awk -F ";" -v OFS="";"" "NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}a[$1]{print a[$1],$0}" f2.txt f1.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: why the double double-quotes for OFS?

Comment: @glennjackman I am using Windows Awk version that is the reason for the double quotes, regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk -F";" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if (a[$1])print a[$1],$0;else print "Not Found", $0;}' OFS=";" f2.txt f1.txt
```

Comment: @sarathi : Why did you remove the OFS and hard-coded the semi-colon ? Any specific reason?

Comment: @Guru, I rolled back to your revision. Don't be afraid of whitespace though, it greatly aids readability.

Answer (score 0):

This was very useful .
I have changed a bit to get data between 2 files and only have 1 column in each file .

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS=";" } FNR==NR { array[$1]=$1; next } { print ($1 in array ? array[$1] : "Not Found"), $0 }' file1 file2
```