# awk compare 2 files, 2 fields different order in the file, print or merge match and non match lines

Tags: file, awk, compare, field

I have two files, and I need to compare the second field from File1 and the first field from File2. 
If there is a match to print the second field of File2 and the entire line matched from File1
If there is no match to print "NOT FOUND" and the entire Line from File1

File1

```
\\FILESERV04\PCO;S:\CA\USII ECOM;/FS7_434D/FILESERV04/BUSII;;;;\\FILESERV04\PCO\;467,390,611 Bytes;11,225 ;157 
\\FILESERV12\MINE$;S:\CA\Naka;/FS3_434D/FILESERV12/NAKA;;;;\\FILESERV12\MINE$\;0 Bytes;0 ;0 
\\FILESERV12\INTEG$;S:\CA\PLOTA;/FS3_434D/FILESERV12/INTEG;;;;\\FILESERV12\INTEG$\;231,094,432,158 Bytes;175,180 ;21,309 
\\FILESERV15\ED$;S:\CA\ED;/FS3_434D/FILESERV12/ED;;;;\\FILESERV15\ED$\;244,594,432,158 Bytes;145,040 ;21,311
```

File2

```
S:\CA\USII ECOM;782
S:\CA\PLOTA;0
S:\CA\Naka;781
```

Desired output:

```
782;\\FILESERV04\PCO;S:\CA\USII ECOM;/FS7_434D/FILESERV04/BUSII;;;;\\FILESERV04\PCO\;467,390,611 Bytes;11,225 ;157 
781;\\FILESERV12\MINE$;S:\CA\Naka;/FS3_434D/FILESERV12/NAKA;;;;\\FILESERV12\MINE$\;0 Bytes;0 ;0 
0;\\FILESERV12\INTEG$;S:\CA\PLOTA;/FS3_434D/FILESERV12/INTEG;;;;\\FILESERV12\INTEG$\;231,094,432,158 Bytes;175,180 ;21,309 
NOT FOUND;\\FILESERV15\ED$;S:\CA\ED;/FS3_434D/FILESERV12/ED;;;;\\FILESERV15\ED$\;244,594,432,158 Bytes;145,040 ;21,311
```

If the field number to compare is the same field number on both files this line works:

```
awk -F";" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if (a[$1])print a[$1]";"$0;else print "Not Found"";" $0;}' File1 File2
```

But is not working here because in this case I have different field number to compare from both files.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [awk Compare 2 files, print match and difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116353/awk-compare-2-files-print-match-and-difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 awk -F";" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if ($2 in a)print a[$2]";"$0;else print "Not Found"";" $0;}'  File2 File1
```

Answer (score 4):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS=FS=";" } FNR==NR { array[$1]=$2; next } { print ($2 in array ? array[$2] : "Not Found"), $0 }' File2 File1
```

Results:

```
782;\\FILESERV04\PCO;S:\CA\USII ECOM;/FS7_434D/FILESERV04/BUSII;;;;\\FILESERV04\PCO\;467,390,611 Bytes;11,225 ;157 
781;\\FILESERV12\MINE$;S:\CA\Naka;/FS3_434D/FILESERV12/NAKA;;;;\\FILESERV12\MINE$\;0 Bytes;0 ;0 
0;\\FILESERV12\INTEG$;S:\CA\PLOTA;/FS3_434D/FILESERV12/INTEG;;;;\\FILESERV12\INTEG$\;231,094,432,158 Bytes;175,180 ;21,309 
Not Found;\\FILESERV15\ED$;S:\CA\ED;/FS3_434D/FILESERV12/ED;;;;\\FILESERV15\ED$\;244,594,432,158 Bytes;145,040 ;21,311
```

Comment: why do you explicitly print the ORS? `print` would be simpler

Comment: @steve: You could also remove the explicit FS and redundant parts of the print and make it print ($2 in array ? array[$2] : "Not Found"), $0. You'd need FS=OFS=";" in BEGIN instead of -F";" for that, but that's probably appropriate. Otherwise: print ($2 in array ? array[$2] : "Not Found") FS $0