# optimizing this script to match lines of one txt file with another

Tags: bash, optimization, scripting, large-files

Okay so  I am at best a novice in bash scripting but I wrote this very small script late last night to take the first 40 character's of each line of a fairly large text file (~300,000 lines) and search through a much larger text file for matches (~2.2 million lines), and then output all of the results into the matching lines into an new text file.

so the script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
  do
  match=${line:0:40}
  grep "$match" large_list.txt
done <"small_list.txt"
```

and then by calling the script like so

```
$ bash my_script.sh > outputfile.txt &
```

and this gives me all the common elements between the 2 list's. Now this is all well and good and slowly works. but I am running this on a m1.smalll ec2 instance and fair enough (the proccesing on this is shit and I could spin up a larger instance to handle all this or do it on my desktop and upload the file). However I would rather learn a more efficentr way of accomplishing the same task, However I can't quite seem to figure this out. Any tidbits of how to best go about this , or complete the task more efficently would really be very very appreciated

to give you an idea of how slow this is working i started the script about 10 hours ago and I am about 10% of the way through all the matches.

Also I am not set in using bash so scripts in other language's are fair game .. I figure the pro's on S.O. can easily improve my rock for a hammer aproach

edit: adding input and output's and morre information about the data

```
 input: (small text file)
  8E636C0B21E42A3FC6AA3C412B31E3C61D8DD062|Vice S01E09 HDTV XviD-FUM[ettv]|Video TV|http://bitsnoop.com/vice-s01e09-hdtv-xvid-fum-ettv-q49614889.html|http://torrage.com/torrent/36A02E282D49EB7D94ACB798654829493CA929CB.torrent
  3B9403AD73124A84AAE12E83A2DE446149516AC3|Sons of Guns S04E08 HDTV XviD-FUM[ettv]|Video TV|http://bitsnoop.com/sons-of-guns-s04e08-hdtv-xvid-fum-e-q49613491.html|http://torrage.com/torrent/3B9403AD73124A84AAE12E83A2DE446149516AC3.torrent
  C4ADF747050D1CF64E9A626CA2563A0B8BD856E7|Save Me S01E06 HDTV XviD-FUM[ettv]|Video TV|http://bitsnoop.com/save-me-s01e06-hdtv-xvid-fum-ettv-q49515711.html|http://torrage.com/torrent/C4ADF747050D1CF64E9A626CA2563A0B8BD856E7.torrent
  B71EFF95502E086F4235882F748FB5F2131F11CE|Da Vincis Demons S01E08 HDTV x264-EVOLVE|Video TV|http://bitsnoop.com/da-vincis-demons-s01e08-hdtv-x264-e-q49515709.html|http://torrage.com/torrent/B71EFF95502E086F4235882F748FB5F2131F11CE.torrent

 match against (large text file)

  86931940E7F7F9C1A9774EA2EA41AE59412F223B|0|0
  8E636C0B21E42A3FC6AA3C412B31E3C61D8DD062|4|2|20705|9550|21419
  ADFA5DD6F0923AE641F97A96D50D6736F81951B1|0|0
  CF2349B5FC486E7E8F48591EC3D5F1B47B4E7567|1|0|429|428|22248
  290DF9A8B6EC65EEE4EC4D2B029ACAEF46D40C1F|1|0|523|446|14276
  C92DEBB9B290F0BB0AA291114C98D3FF310CF0C3|0|0|21448


 Output: 
  8E636C0B21E42A3FC6AA3C412B31E3C61D8DD062|4|2|20705|9550|21419
```

additional clarifications: so Basically there is a hash which is first 40 charecter's of the input file (a file I have already reduced size to about 15% of original, SO for each line in this file there is a hash in the larger text file (that I am matching against) with some corresponding information now it is the line in the larger file that I would like to write to a new file so that in the end I have a 1:1 ratio of all thing in smaller text file to my output_file.txt
In this case I am showing the first line of the input being matched (line 2 of larger file)and then written to an output file

Comment: Please add some example showing the input and the expected output. Just a few lines...

Comment: search here for examples of `xargs` processing. It might be able to help. Good luck.

Comment: Output is not present in either small or large :-)

Comment: no sorry it's not but I was just coopting the form of the data so you could get the idea ... Ill make it all match now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` solution adopted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13116442/1630171):

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if (a[$1]) print}' small.txt large.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

some python to the rescue.

I created two text-files using the following snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random
import string

N=2000000
for i in range(N):
    s = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(40))
    print s + '|4|2|20705|9550|21419'
```

one 300k and one 2M lines This gives me the following files:

```
$ ll
-rwxr-xr-x 1  210 Jun 11 22:29 gen_random_string.py*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 119M Jun 11 22:31 large.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1  18M Jun 11 22:29 small.txt
```

Then I appended a line from small.txt to the end of large.txt so that I had a matching pattern

Then some more python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

target = {}

with open("large.txt") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        target[line.split('|')[0]] = line.strip()

with open("small.txt") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        if line.split('|')[0] in target:
            print target[line.split('|')[0]]
```

Some timings:

```
$ time ./comp.py 
3A8DW2UUJO3FYTE8C5ESE25IC9GWAEJLJS2N9CBL|4|2|20705|9550|21419

real    0m2.574s
user    0m2.400s
sys 0m0.168s

$ time awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if (a[$1]) print}' small.txt large.txt
3A8DW2UUJO3FYTE8C5ESE25IC9GWAEJLJS2N9CBL|4|2|20705|9550|21419

real    0m4.380s
user    0m4.248s
sys 0m0.124s
```

Update:

To conserve memory, do the dictionary-lookup the other way

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

target = {}

with open("small.txt") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        target[line.split('|')[0]] = line.strip()

with open("large.txt") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        if line.split('|')[0] in target:
            print line.strip()
```

Comment: @FredrikPhil  thanks alot much appreciated ... I am excepting Ansgar Wiechers answer simply because on my ec2 instance I get a memory error running your python script (there's just not enough ram) I ran it on my desktop though and it does work! So I will be keeping it in my back pocket for when I do scale up to a larger instance as I approach launching my application. Thanks again! +1

Comment: Glad I could help. It was an interesting task. Normally you'd use the approach outlined in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036 This one was different.

Comment: @brendanmorrison - BTW updated python-code to reduce memory needed by a factor of almost seven :-)