# Compe 2 Awk Files Print Match / No Match

Tags: awk

New to awk and to programming for the most part.  Trying to compare a couple files for a project and append either MATCH or NO MATCH.

My current awk code is adapted from a different question I was looking into [awk Compare 2 files print match and differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116353/awk-compare-2-files-print-match-and-difference)

My code is:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}{if (a[$0]=$0)print a[$0], "MATCh";else print a[$0], "NO MATCH";}' file1.txt file2.txt >> file3.txt
```

By tweaking it around I can either get all "MATCH" to be appended or all "NO MATCH" to be appended.  Any help would be appreciated and would love to learn what I am doing wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: `=` is not equality check in `a[$0]=$0`, you already used the correct form in `NR==FNR`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for what your script seems to be trying to do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} {print $0, ($0 in a ? "" : "NO ") "MATCH"}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  That seems to have gotten me a bit further however it seems when it comes across an unmatched line it is placing unmatched on the rest of them.  Do you mind explaing the $0 in a ? section?  The rest I think makes sense to me.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: That's just a ternary expression (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) checking if the current line from the current file (file2.txt) existed in the previous file (file1.txt). If it did exist then nothing extra is printed before MATCH otherwise NO is printed before MATCH. The script would not indicate all lines as unmatched after the first occurrence of an unmatched line. To debug - add prints and/or reduce your sample input to the smallest possible set that can reproduce the problem. If you can't figure it out from that, post a question with that sample input/output to get help.

Comment: Thanks!  Your comment helped me get this taken care of.